# UIStepper iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uistepper

I am new in programming, let's say I am still swimming in the ocean. I am trying to set up an UIStepper for change a value on a text field. This value has to change using the decimal number (step value = 0.1), I have read many documents but still not sure from where need to start.

The following is the code I am using:

```
 - (IBAction)valueChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {

     sender.stepValue = 0.1;

     float value = [sender value];
     self.txtRspeed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", value];
```

seems like I get the step Value that I want 0.1 but doesn't show up in the simulator.  I also tried setting as initial value the one in the text field with some code but I still encounter errors.

---

What I am doing wrong?

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {

 _value = txtRspeed.text.floatValue;

 sender.value = self.stepper.stepValue + _value;

 self.txtRspeed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", sender.value];
```

}

- (void)viewDidLoad{

  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.stepper.value = 0.1f;
  self.stepper.minimumValue = -100.0f;
  self.stepper.maximumValue = 100.0f;
  self.stepper.stepValue = 0.1f;

}

I am getting the increment but no the decrement.

If a set the stepper value in a viewDidLoad it start from 0

Comment: Did you try something to implement this? We can help you with some code or an issue were you stuck. How might we know your problem without details..

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=stepper

Answer (score 0):

So create the UIStepper and set its `stepValue` property to 0.1. You can get the current value of the control using it's `value` property.

You'll probably want to create the stepper in your storyboard or .xib file and connect it to an IBOutlet in a view controller so that your view controller can access it easily.

Comment: Not really Helpful at all. Thanks any way